# What’s the significance of the tags in ‘dtLane’

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ,everyone
What is the significance of ‘Dist’,‘PID’,‘Dir’, ‘Apara’,‘r’,‘slope’,‘cant’,‘LW’,‘RW’ in dtlane vector maps?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358814/what%E2%80%99s-the-significance-of-the-tags-in-%E2%80%98dtlane%E2%80%99/) by [NJUST](https://answers.ros.org/users/57405/njust/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

each record represent a waypoint, with
Dist: never used
PID: ID of the point in point.csv
Dir : Orientation of the waypoint
Apara, r, cant: never used
LW: to point to the left waypoint (for lane change)
RW: to point to the right waypoint (for lane change)

---

Originally posted by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) with karma: 443 on 2020-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NJUST](https://answers.ros.org/users/57405/njust/) on 2020-08-09**:
thank you for your answer,and I want to know how to fill all these parameters in the dtlane.csv I created by myself  since the offical VectorMapBuilder cannot generate the dtlane.csv